# How to get assistance from bots?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am trying to practice jungle against bots and i want to ask one of them to help me.

I have tried to click everywhere and use shift/ctrl, but without success.

I have tried to search for it but again without success.

How can I do that?

Comment: It may be best to simply practice jungling in a custom game (if you're timing yourself), or a Normal Draft game. Hopefully Riot will add Advanced Bots or a Sandbox mode sometime in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. League of Legends bots are coded to push lanes as quickly as possible while doing their best to defend against enemies trying to take their own towers.

As soon as the game starts, bots will split themselves up to go 2 bot, 2 top, and 1 mid. They will push for about 15-20 minutes, which is usually the time it takes for at least one tower to fall. At that point, easy bots will usually continue to push their own lanes and maybe come to defend whichever lane is being attacked most forcefully. Intermediate bots will usually start to group up as a 4-5 man team and push a single lane. This continues until either they have taken your nexus, or you've taken theirs.

At no point will any bot of any difficulty try to jungle. They simply do not know how. They might chase you into the jungle if you were low health when they last saw you, but if they lose vision of you for a sufficient amount of time, they'll move back to whatever lane they were just pushing, letting you escape.

In fact, I don't think it's possible to tell the bots to do anything at all. I've seen some reports in the past that pinging an enemy tower or champion will make nearby allied bots focus that target, but I haven't seen any behavioral changes when I do that in Co-op Vs AI games.

Comment: The intermediate bots are so dumb to the point if you make a 3v3 custom game, and a bot starts moving to a particular lane, there is nothing you can do t make them move to another lane. If your Annie bot starts moving to bottom lane, you'll have to go mid or your mid will be defenseless